# Twitter Direct Message Quick Replies

Tags: twitter, bots

How many quick replies can add in twitter direct message? And when can I use this quick reply feature in twitter? which API should I use for sending image in direct message for twitter?

Comment: Please ask questions after you have done a lot of research/tried out some solutions. Hint : If there is no answer in google, then most probably both ways are acceptable or you haven't searched hard enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find all the detail you need

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/direct-messages/quick-replies

if you choose option list then you can mention up to 20 Options in quick reply

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/media/upload

Here you can find Media upload API detail,
after upload media you will get Media Id that id can be passed along with direct message.

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/direct-messages

Comment: Thanks you so much. Last time it was still in beta version. Now it is public.